# Why am I getting an aggregation exception in Spring Data Mongo but not in Mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongo

I have a query that works in MongoDB Shell but it is throwing an "aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)" exception using Spring Data MongoDB when I increase the number of documents to return.

Here is the shell query that returns without error:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{"$skip":0},{"$limit":10000},{"$match":{"_id"="550b2552e4b03562d6329a39"}}], {"allowDiskUse":true})
```

Here is the Spring Data snippet:

```
List<AggregrationOperation> ops = new ArrayList<AggregationOperation>();
ops.add(new SkipOperation(0));
ops.add(new LimitOperation(10000));
ops.add(new MatchOperation(Criteria.where("_id").is("550b2552e4b03562d6329a39")));

TypeAggregation<MyCollection> aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(MyCollection.class, ops).withOptions(Aggregation.newAggregationOptions().allowDiskUse(true).build());

AggregationResults<MyCollection> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, MyCollection.class);
List<MyCollection> myResults = result.getMappedResults()
```

When I limit to say 100 or 1000 records everything works fine. When I increase to 10,000 I get the "aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)" exception.

For reference here are the versions I am using:

```
MongoDB = 3.0.0
Mongo Java Driver = 2.13.0
Spring Data MongoDB = 1.6.0
Spring Data Commons = 1.9.0
```

---

UPDATE:

Background: I came to the aggregate solution because I was exceeding the 32MB sort limit when using a find(). I understand that adding an index will solve this problem. Unfortunately this solution doesn't scale. I want to have sorting on all of our columns in our List Grids which would mean 10+ columns to index. Of course from the UI I could limit sorting to specific columns but once again I am trying to avoid that solution and hence the reason I tried an aggregation.

It appears that using a cursor is my only solution. Can anyone confirm that Spring Data MongoDB does not provide direct cursor support meaning I would have to use MongoDB's API?

Comment: From the [mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/), the `aggregate()` command returns a cursor that the client can iterate over. I'm guessing your Spring client is trying to get all the results back at once, which is evidently too much data.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using RoboMongo (mongo client).
Try using `db.runCommand()` instead of `.aggregate()`.

Is seems that using the aggregate method on some clients will add some data  to the query and allowDiskUse will be ignored.

When I used ranCommand, it worked fine:

```
db.runCommand(
   { aggregate: "collection_name",
     pipeline: [
            {$group: ...}, 
            {$match: ...},
            {$group: ...}
           ],
     allowDiskUse: true
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **outputMode(AggregationOptions.OutputMode.CURSOR)** as ouput option instead of the limited 16MB document by default. See [Aggregation Cursor Usage](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/#aggregation-cursors).

```
Aggregation.newAggregationOptions().outputMode(AggregationOptions.OutputMode.CURSOR).allowDiskUse(true).build()
```

Comment: I had seen that but I was looking for a Spring Data API solution but after further research I don't think there is one. I might have to fall back to using the Mongo DB API.

Comment: This cursor is supported from driver version 2.12.0. You should be able to use it with 2.13.0